# Windows 8 dual monitor wallpaper slideshow

Tags: windows-8, desktop-customization

There have been a number of improvements with multi-monitor compatibility in Windows 8, but how would one go about configuring wallpaper slideshow settings for a second monitor? For instance: I want to display one album on my second monitor, and another on my main monitor. How would I set this up?

Also, is there a way to make the slideshow display the same image on each monitor, rather than it displaying two different images from the same slideshow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this software on Steam, on Greenlight > RobotGizmo's Workshop. It's called **DisplayFusion** and it's not for sale on steam yet, but you can vote if you are down for it! http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=103522088&searchtext=

Answer (score 0):

To have both screens display the same image in a slideshow you will need to do the following:

1. Have both screens running at the same resolution.
2. All wallpapers in the slideshow should be the exact size as the resolutions of the screens
3. When choosing which images to use for the slideshow make sure that the option for 'Picture position' is set to 'Tile'.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for this in Windows 8. The "tile" option does work, but only if all of your monitors are the same resolution.

However, there does exist a free program that can be configured to do this. It's worked out well for me so far: http://johnsad.ventures/software/backgroundswitcher/